# Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65 on React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Executing "npm run ios" keeps failing with the title message, even though it succeeded on Xcode by pressing building button.

```
 Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Soomgo.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Soomgo.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Soomgo -destination id=1F904C3C-8CF2-4AE3-BA4C-648D385D8D1B

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.